# Submit Button only saves one input box

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

I'm trying to collect data from input boxes but the submit button only works for one text box. Is there a simple way to fix this? Code:

```
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <title>Yeet!</title>
  <style>
    html {
        background-color: #181818;
    }
    body {
        color: lightgray;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just don't want all of my text boxes to have a submit button. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `<input>` should have an unique name:

```html
<input type="text" name="textdata_a"><br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="textdata_b"><br>
```

`$_POST` will contain all those keys with the user input as value:

```php
$textdataA = $_POST['textdata_a'];
$textdataB = $_POST['textdata_b'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inputs all have the same name, which is why the browser effectively only transmits one of them.

```html
<input type="text" name="textdata">
<input type="text" name="textdata">
```

Give them different names and access them this way on the PHP side:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstline">
<input type="text" name="secondline">
```

And in PHP:

```php
$_POST['firstline']; // will contain the data of the first input-element
$_POST['secondline']; // will contain the data of the secondinput-element
// and so on...
```

If you however need a indefinite number of input fields you can also use an array for that:

```html
<input type="text" name="mytextdata[]">
<input type="text" name="mytextdata[]">
```

And in PHP:

```php
$_POST['mytextdata']; // will contain the data of ALL the input fields as an array
```

You could (for example) merge them together like this:

```php
$dataOfAllInputs = implode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['mytextdata']);
```

However, for such cases using a [textarea HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) might be more reasonable.

Comment: I tried both answers but they don't work. I still marked as answer because they both seem correct to me. Any chance you could upvote though :) I'm trying to get enough rep so i can have     comment on other people's post privilege.

Comment: They both should work, double check you understood exactly what we are saying. Otherwise, explain what kind of behaviour you are having trouble with now.

Comment: Just where to put the stuff. Like on the top or bottom part of this:  
             if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');